# it is strange that I am probably not a Google+ user yet I can login to stackexchange sites

Tags: support, login

I don't believe I am a Google+ user and I am trying to minimize my use of Google products. I believe that I took a specific action to ensure I am not a Google+ user at some point in the past. I do use gmail and I am under the impression that if I use gmail, I have at some point in time been classified, on Google's initiative and perhaps without my knowledge of it (because I don't want to read boring user agreements), as having a `Google Account`. I believe that `Google Account` is sufficient to allow logging into stackexchange websites.

However, the logo on the stackexchange login appears to be a Google+ logo.

Is the logo the wrong logo and should it be replaced with some sort of `Google Account` branding?

Answer (score 3):

I believe Google's OpenID provider is considered to be under the auspices of Google+ *in terms of branding*, which, indeed, is technically separate from having a Google+ account.

All you actually need is to have a Google Account, which means you have an email address (which may not even be Gmail-backed) that's associated with a username and password that you use to login to Google services. Or, conversely, if you have an `@gmail.com` email address, then the username/password you use to log into that Gmail account  *is*, also, a Google Account.

So, technically, you could have a hotmail (or your own custom mail provider) email address, and *only* have a Google account for login to services like Google Play or Stack Exchange. There is not really much that Google tries to do to "bundle" a bunch of their services together; you can easily take what you want and throw away the rest.

Comment: Google doesn't speak OpenID anymore (only OAuth), but yes, it treats all accounts the same regardless of G+ status.